# python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory docker-compose run

Tags: python, django, manage.py

I tried run django project with code

```
docker-compose -f local.yml run --rm django python manage.py runserver
```

but i had such problem:

```
python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

in another computer this project run

[image]

but this code work

```
docker-compose -f local.yml run django python
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your output as next, not as a screenshot!

Answer (score 0):

I get that error when I am working in the wrong directory as the manage.py. Double check which directory that you are in.